# Adjacency Matrix In Java Time Complexity

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-matrix

in java, creating a ADJACENCY MATRIX takes O(V*V) , but since when we create a 2D boolean array in java, all the initial values of the elements are false, and for each edge that we enter we need to update the vertex values to TRUE... so the time complexity must be O(E), where E is the number of edges!!!  am i wrong somewhere??

Comment: if your allocation performs initialisation, it's considered linear in the number of allocated elements, thus simply allocating `V*V` elements is `O(V*V)`

Comment: but its initialised to false automatically when we have created the 2d array.... so will this also have to be counted in the time complexity???

Comment: how do you expect it to be initialised *automatically*? by dark magic? or by a loop?